# Group ID Deformers inaccurate in Maya 2019 and 2022 API

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

So I have written a custom reader and writer for wrap and cv wraps to have the ability to save and rebuild these deformers easily.

Example test on wrap
In Maya 2019,

```
geom_plug = self.getAttrAsMPlug("input[0].inputGeometry")
group_id_plug = self.getAttrAsMPlug("input[0].groupId")
return group_id_plug.getValue()
```

Value returned in maya 2019 is 5 but in Maya 2022 is always 0. Has anyone else faced this issue or is there any other way to get accurate group ids from deformers in Maya 2022 API?

Thanks,
DX

```
geom_plug = self.getAttrAsMPlug("input[0].inputGeometry")
group_id_plug = self.getAttrAsMPlug("input[0].groupId")
return group_id_plug.getValue()
```

Result should be 5 but getting 0 in Maya 2022